# Designing action Bar in android

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

[image]

Does anyone know how I can achieve the triangle shaped box for the new fragment. It should be place right below the item clicked in the action bar.

Answer (score 0):

Create your action bar icon as action views. Then you can modify their appearance in any way you want.

Comment: So this is just changing the image of the action bar icon when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement a visual design that represents your app's brand, the action bar allows you to customize each detail of its appearance, including the action bar color, text colors, button styles, and more. To do so, you need to use Android's style and theme framework to restyle the action bar using special style properties.

check out this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html